# Dropbox Special Window Doesn't Appear?

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, dropbox

There is a special type of window that can be summoned by right clicking on the dropbox icon in the taskbar, and clicking `open dropbox folder`. This window appeared a more whitish color against my dark breeze desktop theme, and allowed sharing files, and copying links to files straight from my desktop. But lately, after I did a fresh reinstall of Kubuntu, and thus Dropbox, whenever I do this procedure, I only get a fresh copy of dolphin, with no sharing options available (Normally there is a dropbox tab on the right click dropdown menu for sharing files). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is dropbox assigned to work with dolphin? As I know, Dropbox suitably integrates to nautilus.

Comment: I think @Redbob has nailed it. Your past "Kubuntu" had Unity as well and maybe that caused the difference?

Comment: nautilus is present in gnome too, not only in unity, @DKBose

Comment: @Redbob Yes, but this user had a Unity+KDE set-up previously, not a Gnome+KDE setup.

Comment: @DKBose No, the disk was formatted before the new Kubuntu installation was installed. Only the data from the previous KDE + Unity survived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `dolphin-plugins` using `apt-get` or whatever.

Close all open instances of Dolphin, open Dolphin, click on `Control`, `Configure Dolphin`, `Services`, and activate the Dropbox service.

Again close Dolphin and restart it. You'll see an additional option `Move to Dropbox`.

If you right-click on the Dropbox icon in your panel, and click on `Open Dropbox Folder`, you'll see various Dropbox-associated options (boxed in a blue rectangle) in the image below:

[image: Dropbox integration in Dolphin]

Please note that all this is with Kubuntu 16.04 with the kubuntu-backports ppa enabled. Things may be different with other Kubuntu versions.

**Edit:** while you're in the Services tab of Dolphin, you'll see a `Download New Services ...` link. If you click on that and sort by rating, there's a Dropbox service having the second highest rating. However, I won't be trying it.

[image: Dropbox Service Menu]