# Ubuntu 18.04 KDE Dropbox issues

Tags: gnome, kde, dropbox

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the KDE desktop alongside the regular Gnome(-based) DE. Dropbox works fine in Gnome, but has two issues under KDE:

- No Dropbox badges in Dolphin, even after installing the Dolphin dropbox extension (from Dolphin's settings). Badges work fine in Nautilus.
- The notification icon in the panel is semi-functional: it's there, and changes as expected when Dropbox is syncing, but right-clicking on it and clicking on "Recent Files" does not display a list of the, er, most recently synced files.

These two issues combined mean that there is no way to be sure that all relevant files have been synced (short of opening the web client). Google says that the above are *supposed* to work. Any advice?

Note: the second issue (recents not showing) also occurs in Gnome if I move the panel to the bottom (e.g. using Dash to Dock or similar). So maybe the issue is that the Dropbox notifier really wants to be on a top panel, not a bottom panel.

Comment: Re. Dropbox badges in Dolphin, see https://askubuntu.com/a/949139/248158. You may need to install `dolphin-plugins` from the Software Center as well.

Comment: Just checked. Installing `dolphin-plugins` and the Dropbox service gives the badges indicating syncing progress in Dolphin. The color of text of the items being synced (in Details mode) is also different. I see what you see for no entries for Recently synced items when one right-clicks on the Dropbox icon in the panel. This is with pure Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thanks @DKBose. I did install `dolphin-plugins`, but I'll try again. It may also be that installing KDE on top of ubuntu complicates things. I might just bite the bullet and install Kubuntu from scratch.

Comment: Yes, use one or the other. AFAIK, GNOME and KDE don't play well together.